# Operational Error no such column in Django 3.0

Tags: django, django-models

I changed the name of the attributes of one of my models. As soon as I made the change in the `models.py` script, I tried to migrate it using `makemigrations` command, but it kept giving me an error that the email field is non-nullable and the database needs something to populate the existing rows. So I tried to reverse the previous migrations and ran the command `python3 manage.py <app_name> zero`.
After this the previous non-nullable field error was resolved at the command line but as soon as I submit the form at the browser, I run into this Operational error.
The crux of the matter is how to make changes to the attributes of one of the models in `models.py` and deal with the consequent migrations ?

[image]

Comment: if you run makemigrations / migrate you are usually asked for a one-time default, you can then just enter ' ' to run the migration successfuly.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to delete your database or running the python manage.py flush commands when making such changes. If you do not want to do that, just add a one-time default (make sure its the right type).